# Is there any data on the advantage of loading jQuery from a CDN (HTML5BP) vs concatenating and minifying it with the other scripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5boilerplate

I'm using HTML5 boilerplate, and saw that they're separating jQuery from `main.js` and `plugins.js`. I understand that the logic behind this is that a lot of sites use jquery and if you use a cdn there is a big chance that the user will already have it cached.

But since my use of html5 bp utilizes a build step, I could also concatenate and minify jquery with all my other scripts. So:

- Separate jQuery, preferably load it from a CDN, or
- Concat and minify jQuery with all other scripts

From what I understand HTML5 BP doesn't consider the concat/minify option since their boilerplate doesn't include a build step. But since it is an option to me; is there any hard data about what is the best option here, or what the real world differences in performance are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There was a large discussion of this (and other related issues) in a pull request last year](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/pull/1327). You should check out that thread. Lots of detailed discussion.

The reason H5BP uses that set-up is that it's the best **default** solution. If a user of H5BP doesn't do anything else to their set-up, they're guaranteed to get a geographically optimized version of jQuery served to their users from a CDN source with the highest possible chance of hitting the cache lottery.

Beyond a default solution:

- If you've got a global audience and you're going to serve your static assets from a CDN, then it would probably be slightly faster to serve a single file from that CDN.
- If you've got a performance tuned static assets server and you've got a local audience, then you might be faster serving a single file from a static assets server even if it's not on a CDN.

Really, though, testing your set-up against your own geographical audience is the best way to go. It's the only way to answer this question for your site or application.

Answer (score 0):

**Pros :**

-Performances are a little better, because users have it already cached from other sites.

**Cons :**

-If the CDN is down, your site is broken.

-If all your files are concatened in one, you will have only one query on your domain, and it will always be better (IMHO) than a separate query on an external domain.

I personnally will always chose to concatenate.

But in any case, don't over-optimize. If your site is not big, chose what you prefer.
(And I think that if you test both solutions, the results will not be extremely differents)

Comment: Another con to concatenating everything is that when you want to upgrade a 3rd party library, it's a lot more work.  I usually leave 3rd party libraries separate for that reason.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can't assume that users already have it cached. Caches are small and the web is big. Lots of contents is pushed through them. The potential for a cache lottery hit is nice but isn't guaranteed